# Delete folders older than certain age

Tags: vbscript

Here is my function that does not work. It never gets to the delete call because the if statement never evaluates true and I can't figure out why.

```
Function DeleteOldFolders(root, maxAgeInDays)

    Dim fso, ofolder, subFolders
    Set fso = CreateObject ("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    If fso.FolderExists(root) Then

        Set ofolder = fso.GetFolder(root)
        Set subFolders = ofolder.SubFolders

        For Each folder in subFolders
            createdDate = FormatDateTime(folder.DateCreated, "2")

            If (DateDiff("d", createdDate, Date) > maxAgeInDays) Then

                objFSO.DeleteFolder folder, True

            End If
        Next

    End If

    Set objFSO = Nothing

End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why nothing gets deleted is probably that you define `fso`

```
Set fso = CreateObject ("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
```

but then use `objFSO`

```
objFSO.DeleteFolder folder, True
```

and have an `On Error Resume Next` somewhere else in your script (never, **ever** use that unless you know **exactly** what you're doing **and** have sensible error-handling code in place).

Some side-notes (unrelated to the actual problem, but worth considering):

- Always use `Option Explicit`. No exceptions.
- You can use `folder.DateCreated` directly in `DateDiff()`. No need to format the value.
- Your function doesn't return anything, so you'd better make it a procedure.

A simpified version of your procedure could look like this.

```
Sub DeleteOldFolders(root, maxAgeInDays)
  Dim fso, folder

  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

  If fso.FolderExists(root) Then
    For Each folder in fso.GetFolder(root).SubFolders
      If DateDiff("d", folder.DateCreated, Date) > maxAgeInDays Then
        folder.Delete True
      End If
    Next
  End If

  Set fso = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your statement

```
createdDate = FormatDateTime(folder.DateCreated, "2")
```

is wrong, risky, and unnecessary. The second parameter -

> NamedFormat  Optional.  Numeric value that indicates the date/time
>   format used. If omitted, vbGeneralDate is used.

is **numeric** and should be given via the pre-defined constants `vbGeneralDate`, ... .

Whether the resulting **string** is correctly converted to the **date** needed by `DateDiff()` is an open question. So use the consistently typed

```
If (DateDiff("d", folder.DateCreated, Date) > maxAgeInDays) Then
```

Another possible cause of problems is `DateDiff()'`s semantics:

> If date1 refers to a later point in time than date2, the DateDiff
>   function returns a negative number.

What did you pass as `maxAgeInDays`?